# Apollo client - add new item to list following mutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I am working on a react app using "@apollo/client": "3.6.5". In the app a user can create payment requests that are displayed in a list.

I need to add a newly created payment request to the list of payment requests in the Apollo cache following the mutation to create one. The problem is the new payment request is not added to the cached list and Apollo does not output any error messages to explain why.

This is my version of the update function I've copied from the Apollo docs to try and update the cache.

```
 const [onCreatePaymentRequest, createPaymentRequest] = useMutation<
    CreatePaymentRequest,
    CreatePaymentRequestVariables
  >(CreatePaymentRequestMutation, {
    update(cache, { data: { createPaymentRequest } }) {
      cache.modify({
        fields: {
          paymentRequests(existingPaymentRequests = []) {
            const newPaymentRequestRef = cache.writeFragment({
              data: createPaymentRequest,
              fragment: gql`
                fragment NewPaymentRequest on PaymentRequest {
                  id
                  amount
                  status
                }
              `
            });
            return [...existingPaymentRequests, newPaymentRequestRef];
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

The mutation to create a new payment request:

```
export const CreatePaymentRequestMutation = gql`
  mutation CreatePaymentRequest($input: CreatePaymentRequestInput!) {
    createPaymentRequest(input: $input) {
      paymentRequest {
        id
        amount
        status
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

This is query used to fetch payment requests:

```
export const GetAccountPaymentRequestsQuery = gql`
  query GetAccountPaymentRequests(
    $accountId: UUID!
    $first: Int
    $before: String
    $last: Int
    $after: String
  ) {
    currentUser {
      id
      accountMembers(filter: { account: { id: $accountId } }) {
        edges {
          node {
            account {
              paymentRequests(
                first: $first
                last: $last
                before: $before
                after: $after
              ) {
                edges {
                  node {
                    id
                    amount
                    status
                  }
                }
                pageInfo {
                  endCursor
                  hasNextPage
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

I think the problem may be that payment requests are nested within the schema. Using the useQuery hook I access the payment requests within a component using the following:

```
const paymentRequests = data.currentUser.accountMembers.edges[0].node.account.paymentRequests
      .edges
```

I have tried numerous iterations of the update function to get this to work but so far no luck.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add your paymentRequests query

Comment: @Kn3cht Ive updated my question with the query.